# scipy global optimization with jacobian information

Tags: pytorch, mathematical-optimization, scipy-optimize, nonlinear-optimization

I am currently working on a global optimization problem and in order to speed up the calculations I want to include jacobian information in the local optimization. My function is not simple but it should be differentiable, and as such I want to use pytorch for the automatic differentiation. Much like it is done here: https://bnikolic.co.uk/blog/pytorch/python/2021/02/28/pytorch-scipyminim.html

```
import numpy
import scipy, scipy.optimize
import torch


def minim(obs, f, p0):
    """Fit function f to observations "obs" starting at p0"""
    
    def fitfn(pars):
        # NB the require_grad parameter specifying we want to
        # differentiate wrt to the parameters
        pars=torch.tensor(pars,
                          requires_grad=True)
        y=f(pars)
        # Simple least-squares fitting
        res=((obs-y)**2).sum()
        res.backward()
        # Note that gradient is taken from the "pars" variable
        return res.data.cpu().numpy(), pars.grad.data.cpu().numpy()

    res=scipy.optimize.minimize(fitfn,
                                p0,
                                method="BFGS",
                                jac=True) # NB: we will compute the jacobian
    return res

# Points on which observations are made
X=torch.arange(100)

def exfn(p):
    y=torch.sin(p[0]*X)+torch.cos(p[1]*X)
    return y

# Sample observations
yp=exfn(torch.tensor([0.3, 0]) )

# Sample run
minim(yp, exfn, numpy.array([0.34, 0.01]))
```

So the above works by providing the keyword jac=True to the minimizer at which point it knows that the function will not only return the value, but also the jacobian when evaluated.
The problem is that I need to use a global optimizer, and it seems like the framework does not support this. At least I can't see any way to tell the global optimizer that my function is returning not just the value but also the jacobian.

With dual annealing it would look something like this:

```
dual_annealing(f,bounds,args=(x,y0),minimizer_kwargs={'jac':True})
```

but this will not work since it only tells the local minimizer that the jacobian is included, but not the global optimizer that is wrapped around the local minimizer.

Is there any workaround for this problem? Or does anyone have any alternative frameworks that might work?

Comment: Why dual annealing then? simulated annealing methods pick a point stochastically, disregarding first and second order derivatives

Comment: I'm not set on dual annealing, but I'm currently trying it because it should have better convergence. I'm specifically including derivative information in the hope that this will speed up the calculations. My problem is a high dimensional global optimization problem, and will for realistic cases have about 500-2000 parameters.

Comment: See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.basinhopping.html for an example of how to use an explicit Jacobian with the basin hopping global solver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having a good discussion about this issue with one of the contributors to scipy on github.

The thread can be seen here:
https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/19305

The topic also brings up Nick ODell's suggestion. And it shows a neat trick with caching the derivative results, which in some cases might be handy.

But overall the conclusion is that the method you should use depends on the specific global and local optimizers you are using, and in some cases you can code something that have no wasted calculations while in other cases there will be some wasted forward or derivative calculations.

Answer (score 0):

There's a slightly more flexible way to specify the Jacobian, which is to provide a callable, rather than True. This lets the minimizer either call the function which provides the function's value, or call the function which provides the function's Jacobian.

Here's how you can change your function to provide the Jacobian to the local search step of the dual annealing minimizer.

```
import numpy
import scipy, scipy.optimize
import torch

def minim_da(obs, f, p0):
    """Fit function f to observations "obs" starting at p0"""
    
    def fitfn(pars):
        # NB the require_grad parameter specifying we want to
        # differentiate wrt to the parameters
        pars=torch.tensor(pars,
                          requires_grad=True)
        y=f(pars)
        # Simple least-squares fitting
        res=((obs-y)**2).sum()
        res.backward()
        # Note that gradient is taken from the "pars" variable
        return res, pars

    def fitfn_val(pars):
        res, pars = fitfn(pars)
        return res.data.cpu().numpy()
    
    def fitfn_grad(pars):
        res, pars = fitfn(pars)
        return pars.grad.data.cpu().numpy()

    bounds = [(0, 1)] * 2
    res = scipy.optimize.dual_annealing(fitfn_val,
                                        bounds,
                                        maxiter=1000,
                                        minimizer_kwargs={'jac':fitfn_grad})
    return res


# Points on which observations are made
X=torch.arange(100)

def exfn(p):
    y=torch.sin(p[0]*X)+torch.cos(p[1]*X)
    return y

# Sample observations
yp=exfn(torch.tensor([0.3, 0]) )

# Sample run
print(minim_da(yp, exfn, numpy.array([0.34, 0.01])))
```

Note: I picked a `bounds` parameter for you, as that's required when using dual annealing. You may have to change it for your application.

Note: This is not 100% reliable. It fails to find the minimum about 10% of the time. You can raise `maxiter` to make it more reliable, at the cost of speed.